# Show loading in browser while form submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I am using AJAX to get some data and fill-up the form. Data is quite large so it takes some time to get from DB and fill up in fields, so while all doing this stuff i am showing loading icon.

Now there is a submit button in a form, and we want - that form should not be submitted until that loading icon gone away. I have done this thing so far.

I am using prevent default - if user hit the submit button before AJAX done its work and that loading icon gone away, and after AJAX done its work that form got submitted.

But now issue is, if i hit submit - because of prevent default is doesn't shows loading icon in browser tab (so user might think form submit button isn't working and hit it multiple times,(we got this data from GOOGLE ANALYTICS))
but form will automatically submits, when AJAX completes it works.

Is it possible to show that "Browser Tab Loading Icon" ?

I know other things like (hide submit button and etc etc)

Here is my piece of code :

```
$("#formsech").submit(function(event){
submit = -1;
    if ( $("#loading").css('display') == 'none' ){
submit = 1;
    }
    else{
 event.preventDefault();
    }
});

setInterval(function(){
    if(submit == -1){

if($("#loading").css('display') == 'none' ){
    submit = 1;
}
}
}, 100);

setInterval(function(){ 
if(submit ==  1){
$("#formsech").submit();
submit = 0;
}
}, 100);
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: When the ajax is called disable the submit button and when the ajax call is done enable it again?

Comment: Thanks for your comment -But as i mentioned "I know other things like (hide submit button and etc etc)" we don't it like that.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using AJAX, you can do simply like this:

```
$(form).submit(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(form).css("cursor", "loading");
  $("#loading").show();
  $.post("/path/to/url", $(form).serialize(), function () {
    $("#loading").hide();
    $(form).css("cursor", "initial");
    alert("Saved");
  });
});
```

A better example using a `setTimeout` just for demo purpose.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".loading").removeClass("hidden").hide();
  $("#myform").submit(function() {
    $(".loading").fadeIn();
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".loading").fadeOut();
    }, 2000);
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
}
.loading {
  background: url("http://www.arabianbusiness.com/skins/ab.main/gfx/loading_spinner.gif") center center no-repeat;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
#myform {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 150px;
  line-height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<form action="." id="myform">
  <div class="loading hidden"></div>
  &nbsp;
  <input type="submit" />&nbsp;
</form>
```

The `setTimeout` is just for mimicking the AJAX delay. The `z-index` will not allow the user the press the submit button.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below html in your page.

```
<div id="overlay"></div>
```

The css will be

```
#overlay {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    z-index: 99;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
}
```

Before ajax call use following code

```
$("#overlay").show(500);
```

After ajax call is completed write this:

```
$("#overlay").hide();
```

Comment: Nice attempt. Please explain how is this better than my answer.

Comment: I was busy answering, I didn't saw your answer. Yes yours is better but mine is simple and self explanatory. It depends to whom the person who is asking connects better. By the way, is there really a need to use setTimeout(), think over it again.

Comment: So you didnt read my answer. *The setTimeout is just for mimicking the AJAX delay.*